# Dynamics 365: Are portal comments supposed to show up in Audit History?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-portals

When a "portal comment" is added to a case, it is not logged to the cases Audit History. Is that an error or to be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portal comment is a child activity (another entity record) of the case entity, that’s why it’s not showing in case audit history. Only case record attribute changes will be in case audit history.

The activities including portal comments will be listed under Timeline and Activities list, not in audit history.

[Troubleshooting related to Portal comments](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2018/05/13/portal-comment-not-showing-up-dynamics-portals/)